# Is it safe initialize enum class reference with an integer?

Tags: c++, enums, casting, reference, reinterpret-cast

given enum class Foo

```
enum class Foo : uint8_t
{
    A, B, C
};
```

why does this cast fail?

```
uint8_t X = 1;
Foo& X_ref = *static_cast<Foo*>(&X);
```

but reinterpret cast does not fail?

```
uint8_t X = 1;
Foo& X_ref = *reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(&X);
```

I'm wondering if this cast is safe and I can safely assign enum values of `Foo` to `X_ref` and expect X to be changed accordingly as long as type of X is same as underlying type of enum class (in this case `uint8_t`)

Comment: The beauty of `reinterpret_cast` is it's the Word of God. The compiler does exactly what you tell it to do no matter how stupid. You can't really make a `reinterpret_cast` fail at the compiler. You did something else wrong if it looks like you did. Unfortunately, it's laughably easy to make the result fail at runtime.

Comment: Oh cool, actually i haven't tested in my program yet (I've tested with an online compiler and it worked) but I thought I would ask first before proceeding. @user4581301

Comment: Anyway you're trying to convert pointers, NOT the enum. `Foo X_ref = static_cast<Foo>(X);` will convert politely.

Comment: `Foo& X_ref = *static_cast<Foo*>(&X);` if the RHS compiled (not tested) it would create an rvalue and you can't bind a non-const lvalue reference to an rvalue.

Comment: But... You want a reference. when you convert you get a temporary variable, and references to temporaries are useless. The temporary is gone before you can use the reference. Yeah. What Richard just said.

Comment: Clang gives a really good error message explaining the above: https://godbolt.org/z/rGf361n9E

Comment: @user4581301 That code is unrelated to the code in the question.

Comment: @RichardCritten It does not compile. What r-value are you talking about?

Comment: @273 Yes. Deliberately simplified to prove a point.

Comment: but the reinterpret cast does not create a temporary right? how about this one?`reinterpret_cast<Foo&>(X);` @user4581301

Comment: Can't say I've ever tried to cast something to a reference.  I'd have to do some diving to see what that one does.

Comment: think long and hard before using enums at all - usually a sign of basically very weak typing - whenever i think of writing an enum in my code, i think "whoa, design error"

Comment: Pretty much the whole point of `enum class` is  it makes it hard to play games like this and spits out errors when you do it. You use `enum class` when you **don't** want people converting from integers.

Comment: Poked around at `reinterpret_cast<Foo&>(X);`. The `reinterpret_cast` means look at the variable as if it was a different type. It's not going to give you a temporary, so you're safe on that count. And since the underlying type of `Foo` is `uint8_t` I don't think you're violating strict aliasing. If there is undefined behaviour lurking in there, it looks like it's the type that'll consistently manifest the way you expect on regular platforms.